# Insertar código en formulario Access 2010

Tags: ms-access-2010

Necesito instalar un botón en un formulario de *access* que me permita generar un ID alfanumérico específico ya sea para copiarlo o que se inserte automático en una de las columnas de la tabla principal.

El código para crear el ID lo había diseñado previamente en macros de *excel*:

```
Sub Macro_1()
  myValue = InputBox("Tipo de archivo")
  myValue1 = InputBox("Tipo de proceso")
  myValue2 = InputBox("Departamento")
  myValue3 = InputBox("Número de archivo")
  If myValue = "Proceso" Then myValue = "PS"
  If myValue = "Procedimiento" Then myValue = "PO"
  If myValue = "Instructivo" Then myValue = "IN"
  If myValue = "Documento" Then myValue = "DO"
  If myValue = "Formato" Then myValue = "FO"
  If myValue1 = "Gerencial" Then myValue1 = "GE"
  If myValue1 = "De soporte" Then myValue1 = "SO"
  If myValue1 = "Orientado al cliente" Then myValue1 = "OC"
  If myValue2 = "Ventas" Then myValue2 = "01"
  If myValue2 = "Compras" Then myValue2 = "02"
  If myValue2 = "Recursos humanos" Then myValue2 = "03"
  If myValue2 = "Manufactura" Then myValue2 = "04"
  If myValue2 = "Calidad" Then myValue2 = "05"
  MsgBox (myValue + "." + myValue1 + "." + myValue2 + "." + myValue3)
```

Answer (score 1):

El editor de macros en MS Access 2010 es completamente diferente al editor de macros de Excel. En [Introducción a la programación de Access *Se aplica a: Access 2010*](https://support.office.com/es-ES/article/Introducci%C3%B3n-a-la-programaci%C3%B3n-de-Access-25EDAEFE-E917-4608-8BA0-DAB7C75CBE0C), se explica de la siguiente forma

---

> NOTA: Muchos de los programas de Microsoft Office utilizan el término
> "macro" para hacer referencia a código de VBA. Esto puede resultar
> confuso para los usuarios de Access porque en Access, el término
> "macro" hace referencia a una colección de acciones de macro que puede
> ensamblar con el generador de macros. Acciones de macro de Access
> representan únicamente un subconjunto de los comandos disponibles en
> VBA. El generador de macros ofrece una interfaz más estructurada que
> el Editor de Visual Basic, lo que le permite agregar programación a
> los controles y objetos sin necesidad de obtener el código VBA.
> Recuerde que en los artículos de Ayuda de Access, las macros de Access
> se conocen como macros. Por el contrario, código VBA se conoce como
> VBA, código, una función o un procedimiento. Código VBA se incluye en
> los módulos de clase (que forman parte de los formularios individuales
> o informes y normalmente contienen código únicamente para los objetos)
> y en módulos (que no están vinculados a objetos específicos y
> normalmente contienen código "global" que se pueden usar en toda la
> base de datos).

En el mismo artículo, más adelante se indica

---

> #### Usar el Asistente para botones de comando para realizar tareas comunes de programación
>
> Si va a agregar un botón de comando a un formulario, el Asistente para
> botones de comando puede ayudarle a empezar con la programación. El
> asistente le ayuda a crear un botón de comando que realiza una tarea
> específica. En un archivo de Access 2010 (.accdb), el asistente crea
> una macro que está incrustada en la propiedad OnClick del botón de
> comando. En un archivo .mdb o .adp, el asistente crea código VBA,
> porque las macros incrustadas no están disponibles en esos formatos de
> archivo. En cualquier caso, a continuación, puede modificar o mejorar
> la macro o el código de VBA que se ajuste mejor a sus necesidades.

y continúa con las indicaciones pasos a paso.

Otros recursos de la ayuda de Microsoft

- [Vídeo: Crear una macro - *se aplica a Access 2010*](https://support.office.com/es-ES/article/V%C3%ADdeo-Crear-una-macro-de-datos-22023611-809C-4928-8858-9FF5F81EB7FF)